# Create rounded highlight in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

[image]

So I'm trying to figure out how to add a curved little highlight to the right of this rounded rectangle. I have a highlight underneath (in it light green), but I can not for the life of me create one to sit beside this rounded rectangle.

I tried to draw it with the pen tool, but it looks "off" I tried to use the shape builder but that just gives me a semi circle. When I add the stroke, it obviously strokes the full object.

Any ideas?? I'm using AI CC.

Comment: Can you maybe Photoshop us up a quick visualization of what you're trying to accomplish?  I think I have an easy way to accomplish this, using strokes, but I need to make sure we are on the same page.

Answer (score 6):

Just going off of what I picture in my head that you are after.  I would use a circular path, stroked, with a round cap:

[image]

Select which Anchor Point(s) you'd like removed and delete:

[image]

Add a round cap:

[image]

Voilà:

[image]

When you get your highlight how you want it, I would suggest expanding its appearance (Object > Expand).

**Edit**
I just realized that I made my highlight *inside* the rectangle and not *beside* it, but the method is still the same, regardless of where the highlight gets placed.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. It didn't even dawn on me to just delete the anchor points.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to [Manly's answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/73146/52050)—If you are working with irregular shapes, you can use the Offset Path function (**Object → Path → Offset Path...**) to get the paths you need. Use a negative value to inset and a positive value to outset.

[image: Offset Path]

Delete the parts you don't need, set a stroke etc:

[image: Stroked Highlights]

Comment: Thank you! I also didn't think of this method. Very helpful for odd shapes. Thanks!